# Write the query to update the document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following mapping and indexed document:

```
  "my_locations": {
    "aliases": {

    },
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          },
          "name_e": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "province_e": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

With the following query I have inserted a data

```
PUT my_locations/_doc/1
{
  "location" : {
      "lat" : 40.92,
      "lon" : -71.34
  }
}
```

where I forgot to add name_e & province_e to above query. How can I write update query to insert name and province for doc 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this using the [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document):

```
POST my_locations/_doc/1/_update
{
  "doc" : {
      "name_e": "some name",
      "province_e": "some province"
  }
}
```